# C, Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue error

Tags: c

I was doing a project that is basically a calendar, and in the "IF" condicion to see if the year is a leap year, a got an error on the first variable "year" saying "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

```
int month, year;
char *months[] = { "Janeiro","Fevereiro" ,.........., "Dezembro" };
int ndays[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    if ((year%4==0&&year%100=!0) || (year%400==0))
        ndays[1] = 29;
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `=!` is not an operator. `!=` instead.

Comment: Typo ```year%100=!0``` shall be ```year%100!=0```

Comment: You're trying to assign `1` to `year % 100`, which isn't a modifiable lvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use != instead of =!
The comparison should be !=

Comment: Can't believe it was it. Thank you!